# Combine multiple SQL queries into single result

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to get the result of 2 queries into a single result set. I'm using SQL Server 2019 Express.

Here is the data I'm working with:

Table `Sales`

| SaleDate | SaleAmt | CustomerID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 11/1/2021 | 500 | 123 |
| 11/1/2021 | 100 | 234 |
| 11/1/2021 | 300 | 345 |
| 11/2/2021 | 500 | 456 |
| 11/2/2021 | 100 | 567 |
| 11/2/2021 | 200 | 678 |

Table `Customers`

| CustomerID | CustomerName |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | Jon Doe |
| 234 | Jane Doe |
| 456 | Bob Doe |
| 678 | Jim Doe |

Query #1:

```
select sales.saledate, sum(sales.saleamt) as 'Total Sales from All' 
from Sales 
group by sales.saledate
```

Query #2:

```
select sales.saledate, sum(sales.saleamt) as 'Total Sales from Customers'
from Sales 
where sales.customerid in (select customerid from customers) 
group by sales.saledate
```

This is my desired result:

| SaleDate | Total Sales from All | Total Sales from Customers |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 11/1/2021 | 900 | 600 |
| 11/2/2021 | 800 | 700 |

Answer (score 1):

you can use join on the date of the sale

```
select s1.saledate, All_Total AS 'Total Sales from All', CustomersTotal as 'Total Sales from Customers'
from (
         select sales.saledate, sum(sales.saleamt) as All_Total
         from Sales
         group by sales.saledate
     ) s1
         inner join
     (
         select sales.saledate, sum(sales.saleamt) as CustomersTotal
         from Sales
         where sales.customerid in (select customerid from customers)
         group by sales.saledate
     ) s2 on s1.saledate = s2.saledate
```

Answer (score 0):

you can combine it in one single query using `case` expression.

```
select s.saledate, 
       sum(s.saleamt) as [Total Sales from All],
       sum(case when exists 
                     (
                         select * 
                         from   customers c 
                         where  c.customerid = s.customerid 
                     ) 
                then s.salesamt 
                end) as [Total Sales from Customers]
from   Sales s
group by s.saledate
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `LEFT JOIN` with conditional aggregation

```sql
select
  s.saledate,
  sum(s.saleamt) as [Total Sales from All],
  sum(case when c.customerid is not null then s.saleamt end) as [Total Sales from Customers]
from Sales s
left join customers c on s.customerid = c.customerid
group by s.saledate;
```